# How do I produce a scatter plot in which the colour of the dots is defined by their y value

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

I have a similar data to this:

```
values = (1,1,2,2,3,2,1,3,3,2,1,3,2,1,1)
x = range(len(values))
y = values
```

values can only contain either 1,2 or 3, and I am struggling to find a way in which I could produce a scatter plot in which 1,2 and 3 values are coloured differently.

Comment: `sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=values, hue=values)` works just fine without `hue = list(map(str, y))` and `plt.scatter(x, values, c=values)` works just fine, without using seaborn.

Answer (score 3):

Or if using `matplotlib`, you can just do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y, c=y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**`seaborn.scatterplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

values = (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1)
x = range(len(values))
y = values

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.scatterplot(ax = ax, x = x, y = y, hue = list(map(str, y)))

plt.show()
```

[image]